# Formspree in Angular2

Tags: http, angular, post, angular2-services, angular2-http

I'm trying to use formspree with the Angular HTTP Client. Therefore I made an Service which has a `sendMail()` Method. In there I make my headers and a simple test Body. And send it with the `post()` Method. But nothing happens. I dont see any POST Message in the Network Inspector of chrome and I also dont get a response

```
import {Http,Headers,Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class SeoService {
  constructor(titleService: Title ,private http: Http){}

 public sendMail(){
        console.log("send");
        const headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
        });

       return this.http.post("https://formspree.io/test.test@test.net", 
            {
                name: 'test',
                _replyto: 'test@test.com',
                message: "testMessage"
            },
            {
                'headers' : headers
            }
        ).map(res => console.log(res.json()));
    }

}
```

In my Code the email is a valid email and also registered at Formspree

Comment: Do you subscribe to that observable anywhere?

Comment: Oh yeah of course thats the problem thank you. I changed `map` with `subscribe` and not it works fine :)